# How to Build an ODS layer?

Tags: ssis, etl, data-warehouse

sorry for my noob question
I'm working on a project where I have to take data from an excel source and build a small DW from it. so I was thinking of these steps
Source > staging> OLETP > ODS > DW
in the requirements, I have to create an ODS layer so I'm not sure whats my process will be and what exactly needs to be inside the ODS, can you please let me know what steps should I take?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mater of fact ODS Operational Data Store(source) is a database that you need to create every relation or check constraint or any checks in DB for your business to check all data that you want use in data warehouse in this layer you must design database like Normal DB but not normalize and you can get any redundancy that you want.pay attention this design is not base on fact or dimension and it just wants to cleans data for data warehouse